# Windows 10 Cortana backslash in path

Tags: windows-10, cortana

Up until a couple of days ago, I used to be able to type paths into Cortana and press the enter key on the keyboard to open them. Now, as soon as I type a backslash the enter key no longer works, and I can't use the arrow keys to select other items from the list of suggestions -- it's still possible to use the mouse.

If I type C: everything works as expected. When it becomes C:\ the keyboard selection stops. The keyboard selection also stops when using a UNC path such as \\pc

I have no idea what I've done. Any suggestions? Currently running Windows 10 (10586.420)